# Properties of retracts

Tags: general-topology

> Prove the following facts about retracts
>
> $(a)$ A retract of a connected space is connected.
>
> $(b)$ A retract of a compact space is compact.

This was an exercise in *Introduction to Topological Manifolds by John Lee*

However if $X$ and $Y$ are any topological spaces and $f : X \to Y$ is any continuous map between these spaces, then if $X$ is connected so is $f(X)$ and if $X$ is compact, so is $f(X)$ (these are both two separate and really well known theorems in General Topology).

So if $X$ is a topological space and $A \subseteq X$ is a retract, the retraction mapping $r : X \to A$ is continuous, so don't $(a)$ and $(b)$ above follow trivially from the above two theorems, since $r(X) = A$ would be connected (if $X$ is) and compact (if $X$ is)?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think, you're right.

Comment: Yes.  Retracts are surjective by definition, and images of connected (compact) spaces are connected (compact).

Comment: More interesting: in a Hausdorff space a retract is closed.